# Moving files to a new directory with a condition

Tags: mv

I have 100s of files in a directory, and I want to keep only those where a part of first file matches with another file and if condition is not fulfilled than mv all files without its corresponding file, such as I have:

```
 man_xyz_1.txt 
 sig_xyz_1.txt 
 man_abc_1.txt 
 man_ttc_1.txt
 man_ddd_1.txt
 sig_ddd_1.txt
```

here, I want to keep only first two files (`man_xyz_1.txt and sig_xyz_1.txt; man_ddd_1.txt and sig_ddd_1.txt`) as their part of filenames (`*_xyz_1.txt and *_ddd_1.txt`) are matching while want to mv (`man_abc_1.txt and man_ttc_1.txt`) in to another directory as they don't have corresponding file with prefix `sig_*`.
Any help is welcome.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the *opposite*, i.e. looks at all `man_*.txt` files in the current directory and moves all that can be paired up with a corresponding `sig_` file to a `processed` directory.  You can then move the remaining files wherever you need to store them.

```bash
mkdir processed || exit
for name in man_*.txt; do
    if [ -e "sig_${name#man_}" ]; then
        mv "$name" "sig_${name#man_}" processed
    fi
done
```

The parameter substitution `${name#man_}` expands to the value of `$name` with its `man_` prefix string removed.

Note that this assumes that the `processed` directory does not exist.

Testing:

```bash
$ tree
.
|-- man_abc_1.txt
|-- man_ddd_1.txt
|-- man_ttc_1.txt
|-- man_xyz_1.txt
|-- script
|-- sig_ddd_1.txt
`-- sig_xyz_1.txt

1 directory, 7 files
```

```bash
$ sh script
$ tree
.
|-- man_abc_1.txt
|-- man_ttc_1.txt
|-- processed
|   |-- man_ddd_1.txt
|   |-- man_xyz_1.txt
|   |-- sig_ddd_1.txt
|   `-- sig_xyz_1.txt
`-- script

2 directories, 7 files
```

Comment: Working completely fine